# Creation of an angular library, loaded on GitLab and shared from multiple projects

Tags: npm, gitlab, angular-cli, angular-library

I would like create a angular library that I can shared with different angular projects.

This library will be loaded on a private GitLab repository and I would like install it with this command

```
npm install my-lib
```

Anyone can help me to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is not efficient. GitLab is not relevant, so I'd remove from the title and description and tags. You should direct your question on "how to create npm packages" and "how to publish my npm package". Or maybe even "how to create private npm repository"

Comment: @JoaoCunha I would argue that GitLab is very relevant in this context, since GitLab serves as an NPM registry for its projects.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the [GitLab NPM Registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/packages/npm_registry.html)? It describes the steps you need to take to push NPM modules to your project's registry.

Comment: I beg your pardon. I misunderstood your question. After going through those steps, do you still have problems with it?

Comment: Thanks @KingChungHuang. I have seen the documentation. But I have not a GitLab premium :(